# JPanel undesirable positions and/or sizes

Tags: java, swing, size, border, jpanel

I'm creating a program in which there are three JPanels - 2 on the top half of the screen, and 1 on the bottom half. Here's the code to position them like so:

`people.setBounds(0, 0, Math.round(getWidth() / 3), Math.round(getHeight() / 2));`
`resources.setBounds(people.getX() + people.getWidth(), 0, Math.round(getWidth() / 3), Math.round(getHeight() / 2));` 
`neighboring.setBounds(resources.getX() + resources.getWidth(), 0, Math.round(getWidth() / 3), Math.round(getHeight() / 2));`

 But unfortunately, this is the result I get: [image]

I was trying to get the panels to fit the window perfectly, but as you can see, they were a bit larger than expected. Some help, please?

Answer (score 3):

Use the layout managers, not setBounds, and let the layouts do the work for you. Your GUI could be created with minimal code by nesting some JPanels that use a simple GridLayout.  For more on this, please check out [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Ok, but with a GridLayout, I can't make my "Neighboring Civilizations" Panel fill the second row; and with a GridBagLayout, the sizing is really, really tiny for some reason...

Comment: @Daniel -- why can't you make your JPanel fill the second row?  The overall GUI uses GridLayout(2, 1) for two rows, 1 column. Then in the upper row you add a JPanel that uses GridLayout(1, 2) which stands for 1 row, 2 columns. In the  upper row panel, you add "people of the..." and "resources" JPanels, and in the bottom row of the main GUI you add the "Neighboring Civ..." JPanel. The key is to *nest* JPanels that use their own layouts.

Comment: I actually thought of another panel ("Statistics") - I just created a new GridLayout(2, 2) and that works perfectly. Thanks!